# WinUI 3.0 - UWP: Error on WebView2 Print functionality

Tags: c#, uwp, winui, webview2, winui-3

In my [WinUI 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/) - UWP project, I have a `WebView2` control that displays a simple html as follows. But when I call the following `javascript` code using [ExecuteScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2#executescriptasync) (as shown below), I get the following error:

**Error**:

> > Check your printer or select another printer. The printer you chose isn't available or isn't installed correctly.

**Screenshot of Error**:

[image]

**Remarks**: There is nothing wrong on my Windows 10's default `Print to PDF` printer as I can print the exact same html page from a browser (MS Edge or Google).

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong here, and can we resolve the issue? I think a cause of the issue may have something to do with how I'm using the JavaScript in my html and/or how I'm passing a parameter to the `ExecuteScriptAsync(...)` method. Note: `wvTest`, as you may have guessed, is the name of WebView2 control.

**Code**:

```
//Correctly displays the html page with a simple text: `Test paragraph`
private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string sHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
        "<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" +
        "<head>" +
            "<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />" +
            "<title>Test Title</title>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
            "<p>Test paragraph</p>" +
            "<script> window.print();</script>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sHTML);
    wvTest.NavigateToString(sHTML);
}
```

//This event opens the `Print Dialog` with the message shown above:

```
private async void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await wvTest.ExecuteScriptAsync(javascriptCode: "window.print();");
}
```

Comment: @PoulBak Agreed. Replaced with `UWP`.

Comment: @PoulBak That's what I had done. I may not have clicked on `Save Tags` button. I re-did it now.

Comment: Have you checked with another printer, like text printer or print to file?

Comment: @PoulBak That dropdown for `Printer` selection (shown in the image above) is not letting you see the other choices. I don't know why because all the code I have is shown all in this post. I have not set any printer options in the code. However, if I print the same html manually from a browser, the printer gives all other options to select. Maybe, it's happening since `WinUI 3.0` is still in preview until this November. However, according to this [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/42) post, the `window.print();` should work.

Comment: I have the same bug, I think it is still not solved for UWP

Comment: May be related: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2894