# WebView2 how to run Javascript function?

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

In my WebView2 i load my local html with js file, all works fine, but how can i run a script from my WinForm in WebView?

Till now i was using webBrowser in VB and i was doing it like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("addProducts", New String() {"{ ""desc"": ""test"", ""qta"": 1, ""prezzo"": 2}"})
```

And now i was trying something like:

```
private async void prodotto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("addProducts(\"{ \"desc\": \"test\", \"qta\": 1, \"prezzo\": 2})\"");
}
```

I've tryed it even like :

```
private void prodotto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddProduct();
}

async void AddProduct()
{
    await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("addProducts(\"{ \"desc\": \"test\", \"qta\": 1, \"prezzo\": 2})\"");
}
```

But the script is not even reached...

Comment: You have typo: `addProcuts` should be `addProducts` !!!

Comment: @PoulBak i just writed it by hand, in actual code it's write correctly

Comment: May be see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835549/equivalent-of-webbrowser-invokescriptstring-object-in-webview2/62840636#62840636

Comment: Another typo: You're missing `@` in front of your verbatim string.

Comment: @PoulBak the extention from linked question works, but the object sent with `ExecuteScriptFunctionAsync("addProducts", new { desc= "test", qta= 1, prezzo= 2 });` fails in JSON.parse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have typo error in your string, try:

```
"addProducts({\"desc\":\"test\",\"qta\":1,\"prezzo\":2})"
```

Data needs to be encoded as JSON to embed as string , its better to use `SerializeObject`
to convert object to JSON, somthing like :

```
  dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
  obj.desc = "test";
  obj.qta = 1;
  obj.prezzo = 2; 

  string  data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

  webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync($"addProducts({data})");
```

Comment: That's working as expected and i don't need any extention, the issue in JS part was that in old WebBrowser i was passing a string and parsing it while with that solution i don't need more JSON.parse