# HTML with JavaScript file not working on WebView2 inside WPF app

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wpf, webview2

In my `WPF` project, I am using [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf) control that correctly displays regular html files and/or html strings as expected. But if the html string contains a script tag with `JavaScript` file as a source, the code from the linked JavaScript file does not work. However, if I copy the exact same generated HTML string to a local file on my drive and save it as an HTML file, the same HTML along with the linked JavaScript works fine:

**Remark**: The `JQueryTest.js` file - in the code - is from the second link titled `Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 3.6.0` from [official JQuery download site](https://jquery.com/download/). Since file is quite big I have not included its code here for brevity. But one can download the file from the link for a test if you like.

**Question**: How can we make the `JavaScript` in the following code work. I read the following [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/howto/js#scenario--running-a-dedicated-script-file) but could not figure out how it can be implemented here.

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfJunkWebView2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfJunkWebView2"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Click="btnTest_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <wv2:WebView2 x:Name="wvTest" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string sFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"JQueryTest.js");
    Uri uri = new Uri(sFilePath);
    string uriPath = uri.AbsoluteUri;

    string sHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html>" +
    "<head>" +
        "<script src=\"" + uriPath + "\"></script>" +
        "<script>" +
            "$(document).ready(function(){" +
            "$(\"p\").click(function(){" +
            "$(this).hide();" +
                "});" +
            "});" +
        "</script>" +
    "</head>" +
    "<body>" +
        "<p> If you click on this line, it will disappear.</p>" +
        "<p> Click this text away!</p>" +
        "<p> Click text too!</p>" +
    "</body>" +
    "</html>";

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sHtml); //you can copy this HTML into an HTML file to test that it works.
    await wvTest.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    wvTest.NavigateToString(sHtml); //this line successfully displays HTML inside WebView2 but the JavaScipt code does not work
}
```

**HTML Generated by the above code is as follows**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0011)about:blank -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><script src="file:///C:/tmp/WpfJunkWebView2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/JQueryTest.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){$("p").click(function(){$(this).hide();});});</script></head><body><p> If you click on this line, it will disappear.</p><p> Click this text away!</p><p> Click text too!</p></body></html>
```

**You can format the above html via [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**:
Copy the above html string in a new HTML file in `VSCode`, right click and click on `Format Document` to get the following. One can then open this HTML file to test the above scenario to verify it works without Webview2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0011)about:blank -->
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="file:///C:/tmp/WpfJunkWebView2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/JQueryTest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("p").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
                });
                });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p> If you click on this line, it will disappear.</p>
    <p> Click this text away!</p>
    <p> Click text too!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshot of MainWindow Display**:

When you run the app and click on any of the three lines in the `MainWindow` that line should disappear - but it is not happening. However, this functionality works fine if the generated html is manually saved to a file as an `.html` and then manually opened in a browser (I tested it on MS Edge and Google Chrome).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can you open DevTools and check the console when you try the failing WebView2 scenario? I'm guessing the issue is your NavigateToString content is not allowed to access the file URI. If so, you can either write your HTML to a file and Navigate to a file URI instead of using NavigateToString or you can try using [CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind_) to host the JavaScript file via an HTTP URI instead of a file URI.

Comment: David, I tried your suggestion of using DevTools, and noticed that even before going to dailing WebView2 scenario, I get the following error (when html string is loaded): `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/tmp/WpfJunkWebView2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/JQueryTest.js`. So, issue seems to be the file URI. I did notice that if the `src` is an external URI (not file URI) it works. I'll test your suggestion for a workaround.

Comment: I tried the alternative of writing HTML to a file..... But that works only on first click. For example, if in the above example, when the Test button is clicked the home page shows up with the three lines shown in the image of my post above. And the JQuery script correctly hides any line when you click on that line. But when you click the   Test button again those lines would not show up again (something that does happen if you manually browse that HTML without using .NET app).

Comment: As for `CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping` method, I do not know how to use it locally - what would be the hostname on my Windows 10, for instance, in this example: `public void SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping (string hostName, string folderPath, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind accessKind);`

Comment: `webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
    "appassets.example", "assets", CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors);
webView.Source = new Uri("https://appassets.example/index.html");`  The folderPath can be an absolute path C:\...\appfolder, or a path relative to your app folder like using the app subfolder named 'assets' in the above. The above will navigate to index.html in your assets subfolder of your app folder. The hostname is any hostname you want to pick to have map to a folder on your local machine